# ADO.NET Entity Framework Insert Operation

Tags: ado.net-entity-data-model

I have a problem when I add row to SQL Server. I can add one row but after I can not. I am using ADO.NET Entity Framework and c#.

```
ent.SaveChanges();
```

My error;

> DataServiceRequestException was unhandled by usercode
>
> An exception of type 'System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceRequestException' occurred in Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: An error occurred while processing this request.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you provide the inner exception? And/Or use fiddler to find what error code SQL server is returning on your request?

Comment: Is this error for insert only or for other type of statements, like select, update,delete?, might be permission issue with insert query.

Comment: Could you please show more code?

Comment: How can you solve this problem? By providing more info. :)